# Using htaccess to access pages without file extension

Tags: .htaccess

I'm looking for guidance on using htaccess so that the following URLs will work:

A URL of /blog would go to the page `/blog.php` but keep `/blog` as the URL. I don't want users to see `.php` in links or the URL.

I also want `/blog/` to go to `/blog/index.php` which would of course be normal behavior.

So far I've tried this, which works for `/blog` but not `/blog/`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question with the correct code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```